# How to create multiple urls for a same page contents in wordpress

Tags: urls

For the same page's contents in WordPress, I need to make multiple urls.
Like,
https://www.laundryheap.qa/doha/abu-dhalouf
https://www.laundryheap.qa/doha/abu-sidra
https://www.laundryheap.qa/doha/airport-area-hia

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on 'Duplicate Content' and how it's perceived by Google.

Comment: You want to use a plugin which does custom redirects, otherwise you end up with duplicate content which is bad for SE ranking.